# Check if multiple file with different file types exists in a folder in script task - SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a scenario where i need to check multiple files with different file types exists in a directory after the execution of SSIS package.

i have 2 files one .txt other one .csv in a folder, now every day i need to check whether 2 files present in the folder or not.

So i have created package which has variables with  dynamic expressions.

```
Folder Path : \\server1\testing\  
Folder name : logisticsSummary
```

My files are

```
logisticsSummary.txt  
logisticsSummary.csv
```

So i have taken script and written the below script.

```
string FileFolder = Dts.Variables["User::Fully_Qualified_Folder_Path"].Value.ToString();

        foreach (string filename in FileFolder)
        {
            string FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
            if (FileExtension != ".txt" && FileExtension != ".csv")
            {
                Dts.Variables["User::File_Exist"].Value = 0;
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
            else
            {
                Dts.Variables["User::File_Exist"].Value = 1;
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }
        }
```

When i am executing the package it is throwing error

> Error: The binary code for the script is not found. Please open the
>   script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it
>   builds successfully.

i have set delay validation property to true, not sure where my code went wrong. Any other approach in achieving this.

Comment: I suggest you avoid using scripts if possible as there are many things that can go wrong. I suggest you use a for each file loop instead.

Comment: That error is often caused by errors in the script. Just to be sure, did you build and save your script? Anyways, I would also suggest the for each file loop as Nick said

Comment: i tried with for each loop container and able to capture the filenames(.xls and .csv files) in a variable, now i want to store this filenames in a table , how can i to that using script task or any other component.

Comment: There are many many guides online for this, such as this: http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s359/files-foreach.htm. If you want to run some SQL (to insert into a table) inside your for loop..... you drop an execute SQL task inside your for loop. That's the first job.